# SAS: Mean of last 30 days for CAR

Tags: events, sas

I am about to run an event study and need to calculate the average return of the last 30 days before an event occurred. I.e. if date = eventdate then take the last 30 returns, sum up and average them.

```
Date Symbol Eventdate Return
1/1/2016 AAPL 1/1/2016 0.026
```

This data would trigger that the previous 30 days returns are averaged. The 30 should also be amendable to have different benchmark periods (for example the last 60 to -10 days.

Is there a good way? My do loop skills are not sufficient and lag30(returns) until lag1(returns) is definitely not an option.

Thanks!

PS: If anyone has infos on a GARCH(1,1) event study version I'd be also very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array of temporary variables to host your previous returns.

```
data input_data;
    format  event_date other_date date.;
    do i = 1 to 100;
        event_date = today();
        other_date = event_date - i + 1;
        ret_amount = ranuni(123)*5;
        output;
    end;
    drop i;
run;

proc sort data=input_data;
    by other_date;
run;

%let max = 30;
data averages_returns;
    set input_data;
    array prev_return_array {0:&max} prev_0-prev_&max;

    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        do i = 0 to &max;
            prev_return_array(i) = 0;
        end;
    end;


    do i = &max to 1 by - 1;
        prev_return_array(i) = prev_return_array(i - 1);
    end;
    prev_return_array(0) = ret_amount;

    if event_date = other_date then do;
        sum_return = sum(0,of prev_0-prev_&max);
        output;
    end;
    retain prev_0-prev_&max;
    drop prev_0-prev_&max i;
run;
```

Comment: Perfect, just divided it by &max to get the avg. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Seba's answer works.

**IF** you have continious data (Single observation per line), here is an alternative way using proc expand. It calculates moving sum over 30 days for each row. When you want the sum of particular date, you just select the row and check the result.

When dealing with huge datasets it may prove useful. Also you can do a few tricks to proc expand the data to continuous data, but that's beyond the scope of the question.

```
proc sort data=begin_data; by dateVariable; run;

proc expand data=begin_data out=out_data;
    convert Var_to_sum =s um_30d / METHOD = none TRANSFORMOUT = (MovSum 30);
run;
```